# What is the Pythonic or best practice way of iterating over an integer?

Tags: python, casting, type-conversion

What is the best practice for iterating over an integer in Python? I find that I need to do so often, typically with verbose results. For example, here are two functions I wrote for [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problems:

```
def is_permutation_of(n, m):
    """ Return True if n is a permutation of m, else False
    """
    if len(str(n)) != len(str(m)):
        return False
    for d in str(n):
        if d not in str(m):
            return False
    return True
```

And another:

```
def has_even_digit(n):
    """ Return True if n has an even digit, else False
    """
    evens = ['0', '2', '4', '6', '8']
    for e in evens:
        if e in str(n):
            return True
    return False
```

In addition to the verbosity, 1) there must be a computational expense associated with each type conversion and 2) it just feels completely inelegant. Is there another way of dealing with this issue? Am I going about these functions in entirely the wrong way, i.e. should I not have to ever iterate over an integer?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a heads-up: `is_permutation_of('aab', 'abb')` will return `True`.

Comment: @poke, Thanks for that observation

Comment: From you two comments below, you seem to be asking 'can I do the functions like these WITHOUT converting an int to a str?' You probably can, in a C like fashion, but why? Converting an int to a string is one of the great idioms and shortcuts in scripting languages. If you think it is faster -- it probably isn't. And it is definitely going to be a lot more code.

Comment: An integer is not iterable, so your question as stated doesn't make a lot of sense. After reading the details, you are really talking about iterating over the digits in an integer. In that case, doing a string conversion is a natural next step. But there is no need to do it over and over within your for loop - just one `ndigits=str(n)` at the top will suffice.

Comment: @thewolf, that is exactly what I was asking. From the various answers, it sounds like converting an integer to a string IS the Pythonic way of iterating over the digits. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer my variant instead of your `is_permutation_of`:

```
def is_perm(a,b): return sorted(str(a)) == sorted(str(b))
```

And I think this is better for `has_even_digit`

```
def has_even_digit(n):
    evens=set(['0', '2', '4', '6', '8'])
    return any(c in evens for c in str(n))
```

Or, even use a tuple rather than a set:

```
def has_even_digit(n):
    return any(c in ('0', '2', '4', '6', '8') for c in str(n))
```

---

**Edit**

From the comment thread, I thing you are looking for something like this:

```
# pseudo code -- don't use -- not syntactically correct
for d in 123456:      # integer
   # do something with each digit...
```

This does not work because integers do not support iteration in Python. Additionally, there is no real need have something like an integer iteration since it is so idiomatic and easy to do it with strings.

Here is a Python framework to do it with strings but produce single integer digit:

```
for d in [int(c) for c in str(123456)]:
    # d is a left (most significant) to right integer digit - do what you want with it...
```

If you want the same number right to left:

```
for d in [int(c) for c in str(123456)[::-1]]:
    # Now right (least significant digit) to left (most significant digit)
```

Compare those two simple cases with doing it with actual math with the integer or long:

```
def int_iter(n,reverse=False):
    rtr=[]
    if not isinstance(n, (int,long)):
        raise ValueError('n must be int or long')

    while n:
        rtr.append(n%10)
        n/=10

    if reverse:
        return rtr[::-1]    
    else:
        return rtr
```

It is really a lot easier to use strings and probably faster. If you need blazing speed, do it in C.

Comment: Those are both nice @Pyson, but the functions were just examples of cases where I iterated over an integer; are you saying that no such cases really exist or just improving my functions? Either way, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I personally find `for e in str(n)` very readable.

What I do find less pleasing to the eye are the repeated calls to `str(n)` inside loops (where `n` is invariant).

Anyhow, I would implement both functions completely differently

```
def is_permutation_of(n, m):
   return sorted(str(n)) == sorted(str(m))

def has_even_digit(n):
   if n == 0:
      return True
   while n != 0:
      if n % 2 == 0:
         return True
      n //= 10
   return False
```

Comment: I agree. It's usually better to have a readable solution over an elegant solution.

Comment: @NPE, I agree that that line is fairly readable, but it gets messy once you do things like: `for e in range(len(str(n)))`

Comment: @ggundersen: But why would you do that? Surely you'd just use `enumerate()`?

Comment: Why use `enumerate(x)` if you only need to iterate over the indexes?  `xrange(len(x))` seems better to me.  Of course, `str(n)` is not the best way to get an iterable of the digits of a number in base 10 in the first place.

Comment: @NPE, I said the same to Pyson: I appreciate the optimizations, but I think it misses my larger question, which is: should I simply not be iterating over integers? The functions I posted were simply examples of cases where I thought iterating was useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_permutation_of(n, m):
    return sorted(n) == sorted(m)

evens=re.compile('[02468]')
def has_even_digit(n):
    return evens.search(str(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers aren't "massive" - ie, bringing things to a halt, then you could use your `has_even_digit` as:

```
>>> a = 123456789
>>> any(i % 2 == 0 for i in map(int, str(a)))
True
```

Failing that, an optimisation would be to bitwise with `1` itself - since anything representable by binary must be odd if the first bit is set. Although that relates to the "whole number" - not digits.

Answer (score 0):

For iterating over even digits, you can use [range's `step`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) parameter:

`range(start, end, step)`

So, in your code, you could do:

`for e in range(0, 8, 2):`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generator:

```
def digits(num):
    while num > 0:
        yield num % 10
        num /= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The computational cost for is_permutation_of is easily mitigated if you just store them into separate variables.

```
def is_permutation_of(n, m):
    """ Return True if n is a permutation of m, else False
    """
    sn = str(n)
    sm = str(m)
    if len(sn) != len(sm):
        return False
    for d in sn:
        if d not in sm:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_even_digits(n):
    return bool(set('02468') & set(str(n)))
```